# issue with Method returning the MD5 hash of a string in Java

Tags: java, string, methods, hash, md5

Im an old Java student. Trying to create a method that returns a string variable with the value of a MD5 hash of any string.

Im getting an exception when compiling... "cannot find symbol"

```
public static String hash(String magicString){

        try{

           String hash = null;

           byte[] arrayOfByte = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(magicString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
           for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfByte.length; i++) {
             String string = Integer.toHexString(arrayOfByte[i]);
             if (string.length() == 1) {
               string = "0" + string;
             }
             string = string.substring(string.length() - 2);
             hash = hash + string;

              }

              }catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e){System.err.println("\nCaught Exception: " + e.getMessage()+ "\n\nMmm.. \n");

           }return hash;


       }
```

..thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can not find symbol means that there is a problem in your Java source code

You have to declare the hash variable outside the try catch block

```
public static String hash(String magicString) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String hash = null;

    try {

        byte[] arrayOfByte = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest(magicString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfByte.length; i++) {
            String string = Integer.toHexString(arrayOfByte[i]);
            if (string.length() == 1) {
                string = "0" + string;
            }
            string = string.substring(string.length() - 2);
            hash = hash + string;

        }

    } catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        System.err.println("\nCaught Exception: " + e.getMessage() + "\n\nMmm.. \n");

    }
    return hash;
}
```